# What's the surface measure (volume) of the manifold $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = x_3^2 + x_4^2$, $0 \leq x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq a^2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, manifolds

What's the surface measure (volume) of the manifold $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = x_3^2 + x_4^2$, $0 \leq x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq a^2$?

I'm trying to figure this out in terms of an integral of a manifold but can't quite figure out how. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In which space is the manifold embedded? You have four variables, so that implies $\Bbb R^4$ and the manifold is $3$-dimensional, but you ask for area which implies the manifold is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: Yes it's $\mathbb{R}^4$, I should've said volume.

Comment: I edited your title and question appropriately. Change it if you don't like the result.